# Converting mysqlx::Value to std::string with special characters

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11

I'm trying to convert a mysqlx::Value type that should be a string but it has special non-standard language characters in it. I need to handle it as a std::string or equivalent.

I'm using the mysql C++ Connector XDevAPI to retrieve the data.

```
mysqlx::Session sess(_db_conn_info.db_host, _db_conn_info.db_port, _db_conn_info.db_user, _db_conn_info.db_pass);
    mysqlx::Schema db = sess.getSchema(_db_conn_info.db_name);

    mysqlx::Table artist_table = db.getTable("Artist");
    mysqlx::RowResult artist_result = artist_table.select("id", "a_id", "name", "is_australian")
        .where("id like :artist_id").bind("artist_id", artist_id).execute(); 

mysqlx::Row row = artist_result.fetchOne();
```

The name column in the row[2] value can sometimes contain characters like: é or í

I want to pass the mysqlx::Value result into a std::string object or similar. **Note:** this works fine when the string does not contain special characters.

I've tried using a stringstream but I get "CDK Error: string conversion error" when the string contains the special characters.

```
std::stringstream name;
name << row[2]; // Exception throws here
```

EDIT: ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.3.0

Comment: It also seems that the mysqlx::Value::getType() member doesn't know what type the result is either. I tested against a known good string and it returns type 6 (which is a string). When i run it against a value with the special chars it throws the exception.

Comment: Probably want to be using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/wstringstream/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/

Comment: tried with wchar, no luck. it seems like the column data being pulled back from mysql is unreadable, although querying the db directly via workbench shows the value fine. I'm thinking maybe it's the character set/collation settings but I can't figure out how to set it with the xdevapi?

Comment: Ok, so i can get the type from xdevapi and it understands it to be of type STRING or ENUM 6. But if I try an do anything with it like sstream, wstring, wchar, char, codecvt etc, the compiler keeps telling me there is no way to convert it from a mysqlx::Value type to whatever type I'm trying. The value is encoded as utf8mb4 from the database so the mysql API knows what it is and grabs it. I just can't seem to do anything with it, not even dump the bytes so i can look at what's inside it. Do i need to write a custom type converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was using a version of mysql-cpp-connector that had a known bug with utf8mb4 character encoding. (/tears hair out), upgrading fixed it.